# Filing DS-160 Application, Job Information (US visit visa)

Tags: visas, usa, applications

My dad left the workforce in 1996. and he is retired since then.  Should I mention my dad job information when filling out his application?

Comment: I am sorry I meant to say Online Application

Comment: @Danish Please edit the question to clear that up.

Comment: According to this example https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/PDF-other/DS-160-Example_11012019.pdf the form asks about current employment, and previous 5 years’ if applicable. Is that the same in the version you’re completing?